# issue with foreign key reference in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework

I have a table called mail with a foreign key column called deletedBy which references the users table by pk. when I create a new mail i want to set this field to null as the mail is undeleted, however when i do i get an foreign key constraint failure error.

I totally understand the error, but how do i get around it?

table:-

```
CREATE TABLE `mail` (
  `pk` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `to` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `dt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `read` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deletedby` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`),
  KEY `from_mail__users_pk` (`from`),
  KEY `to_mail__users_pk` (`to`),
  KEY `deletedby_mail__users_pk` (`deletedby`),
  CONSTRAINT `deletedby_mail__users_pk` FOREIGN KEY (`deletedby`) REFERENCES `user` (`pk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `from_mail__users_pk` FOREIGN KEY (`from`) REFERENCES `user` (`pk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `to_mail__users_pk` FOREIGN KEY (`to`) REFERENCES `user` (`pk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

error message:-

```
 ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ajfit`.`mail`, CONSTRAINT `deletedby_mail__users_pk` FOREIGN KEY (`deletedby`) REFERENCES `user` (`pk`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
SQL Statement:
 INSERT INTO `ajfit`.`mail` (`from`, `to`, `subject`, `message`, `read`) VALUES (31, 30, 'test', 'test', '0')
```

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are not providing a value for `deletedby`, the `DEFAULT` value of `0` used.  But there is (presumably) no record in the `user` table with a `pk` of 0 and therefore the foreign key constraint (correctly) fails.

As you have said yourself, you want `deletedby` to have a `DEFAULT` value of `NULL` so that the foreign key constraint is not checked until an alternative value is provided:

```
ALTER TABLE mail MODIFY deletedby int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

The deletedby column in `mail` table should contain the values from id column in `user` table as there is foreign key on id column of `user` table.

Since foreign key constraint accepts NULL values, one way is to have NULL value for deletedby column while inserting new row in `mail` table.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an entry in the user table with the code of 0 attached to it? Because what it looks like to me is that the table trying to find entry 0 with no luck.